# Factors in R - when I set the levels, one factor gets recoded to NA

Tags: r

I have a variable (x) with 4 levels - "Never", "1-2 times a month", "1-3 times a week" and "Everyday". When I try to order the levels using

```
x <- factor (x, levels=c ("Never", "1-2 times a month", "1-3 times a week", "Everyday"))
```

for some reason it recodes "Everyday" to NA and comes up as 0 when I calculate. I've tried putting it as the first, or second level and it does the same thing. When I tried to make dummy data, it worked fine so I can't give an example. I used the exact same code with a Likert variable and it worked fine.

Comment: When this happens to me, it is almost always because I spelled the level wrong.

Comment: why can't you give example? 
try `unique(x)`, does that have the same names as levels

Comment: I don't say that you have misspellings, but some of them can be more tricky spot, like leading and trailing spaces, and extra spaces between words.

Comment: You need to give more information in your question (like the output of `str(x)`) for us to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: I've checked the spelling, and copied/pasted the variable name. The str(x) is: `Factor w/ 5 levels "","1-2 times a month",..: 3 3 3 4 3 3 3 3 2 4 ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a trailing space in the original data file. The label was "Everyday ", not "Everyday". Using the unique (x) I was able to see where the problem was. I was only able to see the problem when I converted it to a character ran the unique(x) function.

Answer (score 2):

As commentors have pointed out, it's likely because of a spelling error somewhere. We can conveniently remove this source of error completely, by reordering the levels of a factor numerically:

For example if your levels are in reverse you could write:

```
x <- factor(x, levels=levels(x)[c(4,3,2,1)])
```

Comment: ...or `unique` if `x` is a character vector. Although it's always a good idea to check the unique values in the raw variable to make sure you don't have errant misspellings there too.

Comment: @joran, `unique` seems to work on integer/numeric/logical vectors as well.

Comment: Right, I assumed from the question the user already had a factor.